# Creating column formatted text with Console.WriteLine()

Tags: vb.net, format, command-line-interface, multiple-columns, console.writeline

I am printing a random "card" to the console with `Console.WriteLine()'.

I am trying to print a line with two parts.  The first part of the line shows the long-name of the card you have drawn.  The second part shows the suit icon and the number:
[image]

Is there a way to show the second part of the line in a neater/uniform way?  Something like this:
[image]

The problem occurs because the first part of my line changes size depending on the face value and suit.  Here is the code I am using to print the card:

```
Console.Write("Your card is a{0} " & textValue & " of " & suit, IIf(textValue = "Ace", "n", ""))
Console.Write("     " & suitIcon & " " & textValue)
Console.WriteLine()
```

I have also tried the following:

```
 Console.Write("Your card is a{0} " & textValue & " of " & suit, IIf(textValue = "Ace", "n", ""))
 Dim string2 As String = (suitIcon & " " & textValue)
 Dim padAmount As Integer = 50 - (suit.Length + textValue.Length)
 Console.Write(string2.PadLeft(padAmount, " "c))
 Console.WriteLine()
```

Which shows the text as:
[image]

Comment: What if you pad the string(s) to X characters in length?

Comment: @Capellan Thank you for your response.  I have updated the question with an attempt to use padding.  It doesn't seem to work how I would like it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution to my problem with help from @Capellan.  I also needed to account for the length of the second part of my string.

I used to following code to do so:

```
        Console.Write("Your card is a{0} " & textValue & " of " & suit, IIf(textValue = "Ace", "n", ""))
    Dim string2 As String = (suitIcon & " " & textValue)
    Dim padAmount As Integer = (25 - (suit.Length + textValue.Length)) + suitIcon.Length + textValue.Length
    If textValue = "Ace" Then
        padAmount -= 1
    End If
    Console.Write(string2.PadLeft(padAmount, " "c))
    Console.WriteLine()
```

This still may not be the best way to do this, so feel free to submit an answer.  It did produce the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what you're pasting as your output, but what about something like this?

```
Module Module1

Dim lstCard As New List(Of String)
Dim lstSuit As New List(Of String)

Sub Main()

    lstCard.Add("Ace")
    lstCard.Add("King")
    lstCard.Add("Queen")
    lstCard.Add("10")
    lstCard.Add("9")

    lstSuit.Add("Spades")
    lstSuit.Add("Hearts")
    lstSuit.Add("Diamonds")
    lstSuit.Add("Clubs")

    For i As Int32 = 0 To lstSuit.Count - 1
        For j As Int32 = 0 To lstCard.Count - 1
            Console.WriteLine("Your card is {0} {1} of {2}.", IIf(lstCard(j) = "Ace", "an", "a").ToString.PadLeft(2), _
                              lstCard(j).PadLeft(5), lstSuit(i).PadLeft(8))
        Next
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

End Module
```

Which outputs:

```
Your card is an   Ace of   Spades.
Your card is  a  King of   Spades.
Your card is  a Queen of   Spades.
Your card is  a    10 of   Spades.
Your card is  a     9 of   Spades.
Your card is an   Ace of   Hearts.
Your card is  a  King of   Hearts.
Your card is  a Queen of   Hearts.
Your card is  a    10 of   Hearts.
Your card is  a     9 of   Hearts.
Your card is an   Ace of Diamonds.
Your card is  a  King of Diamonds.
Your card is  a Queen of Diamonds.
Your card is  a    10 of Diamonds.
Your card is  a     9 of Diamonds.
Your card is an   Ace of    Clubs.
Your card is  a  King of    Clubs.
Your card is  a Queen of    Clubs.
Your card is  a    10 of    Clubs.
Your card is  a     9 of    Clubs.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formatting parameters to control the padding of the output.  The -2 means left align and pad to 2 characters, the 5 means right align and pad to 5 characters:

```
Dim textValue = "Queen"
Dim suit = "Spades"
Dim article As String = IF(textValue = "Ace", "an", "a")

Console.WriteLine("Your card is {0,-2} {1,5} of {2}", article, textValue, suit)

textValue = "Ace"
suit = "Hearts"
article = IF(textValue = "Ace", "an", "a")

Console.WriteLine("Your card is {0,-2} {1,5} of {2}", article, textValue, suit)

textValue = "7"
suit = "Diamonds"
article = IF(textValue = "Ace", "an", "a")

Console.WriteLine("Your card is {0,-2} {1,5} of {2}", article, textValue, suit)
```

Result:

```
Your card is a  Queen of Spades
Your card is an   Ace of Hearts
Your card is a      7 of Diamonds
```